# How to list Service principal permissions using powershell

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-powershell, azure-service-principal

I have to list out the permissions given to a service principal using powershell. Get-AzAdDServicePrincipal cmdlet not giving full details. Can anyone help?
I need the permissions list with claim value and type like in below image
[image]

Comment: Have you looked at [Get-AzADAppPermission](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/get-azadapppermission?view=azps-7.4.0)?

Comment: I tried but I'm getting list objects containing ApiId, Id and type only. But I need permission type and permission claim value

Comment: Please edit your question and include your script and the desired output you want.

Comment: Added image containing list of details I need and I tried Get-AzAdDServicePrincipal, Get-AzADApplication, Get-AzADAppPermission, Get-AzureADServicePrincipalOAuth2PermissionGrant also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am using the AzureAD module for tasks like this one (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/?view=azureadps-2.0).

**Application permissions**

With the cmdlet Get-AzureADServiceAppRoleAssignedTo you can list the application permissions given to your service principal:

```
$rolesAssigned = Get-AzureADServiceAppRoleAssignedTo -ObjectId 'OBJECTIDOFYOURSERVICEPRINCIPAL'
$rolesAssigned | Select-Object -Property *
```

This command returns only the ResourceDisplayName (in your screenshot Microsoft Graph), ResourceId (the ObjectId of the Microsoft Graph app) and the Id of the permission.

If you want to get the permission name and description you can get them with the cmdlet Get-AzureADServicePrincipal:

```
foreach ($role in $rolesAssigned) {
   $servicePrincipal = Get-AzureADServicePrincipal -ObjectId $role.ResourceId

   $servicePrincipal.AppRoles | Where-Object { $_.Id -like $role.Id }
}
```

This will loop through every permission and print out the name, description and other properties.

**Delegated permissions**

For getting delegated permissions of a service principal you can use the Get-AzureADOAuth2PermissionGrant cmdlet:

```
$spDelegatedPermissions = Get-AzureADOAuth2PermissionGrant | Where-Object { $_.ClientId -eq 'OBJECTIDOFYOURSERVICEPRINCIPAL' }
$spDelegatedPermissions | Select-Object -Property *
```

Comment: Thank you but with this I'm getting application type permissions details only. How to get delegated permissions list

Comment: Sorry I didn't check your screenshot very well... I've added a code snippet for delegated permissions to my answer. I hope this will work!