# Getting blank while fetching Delegated permissions of Service Principal via PowerShell

Tags: azure-ad-powershell-v2

I am trying to get the list of delegated permissions that I granted to Service principal by querying via PowerShell like below:

```
Get-AzureADOAuth2PermissionGrant | Where-Object { $_.ClientId -eq  'myappclientid' } | Select-Object -Property *
```

But I am getting blank in response.

I can see the Service principal permissions in my Azure Portal. But still, I'm facing the same error.

Can anyone help me out with what am I missing here?

I'm giving ObjectID of my application registered in Azure AD like this:

[image]

Comment: Could you please include what value you are giving to **`object_id`** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please **note** that when you are registering application in Azure AD it automatically creates a Service Principal under Enterprise Applications with same name but with different **`object_id`**

Make sure to pass that **`object_id`** of your Enterprise application not your registered application like below:

*Go to Azure Portal -> Azure Active Directory -> Enterprise Applications -> Your Application -> Overview*

[image]

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the below results:***

When I passed **`object_id`** of registered application in the query like below I got the same response like below:

[image]

When I passed the **`object_id`** of Enterprise application, I got the delegated permissions successfully like below:

[image]

**References:**

[Apps & service principals in Azure AD - Microsoft Entra | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/app-objects-and-service-principals)

[azure - How to list Service principal permissions using powershell - Stack Overflow  by fabrisodotps1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71779690/how-to-list-service-principal-permissions-using-powershell)